# address space of variables changing in c program

Tags: c, pointers, memory

The address space of an variables seems to be varying in my program. First I got the following output from the program below.

```
int main(){
int a = 10;
int *b = &a;
int **c = &b;
int ***d = &c;
printf("a - address: %p, value: %x\n",&a ,a );
printf("b - address: %p, value: %x\n",&b ,b );
printf("c - address: %p, value: %x\n",&c ,c );
printf("d - address: %p, value: %x\n",&d ,d );
printf("size: a - %d, b - %d c- %d, d - %d", sizeof(a), sizeof(b), sizeof(c), sizeof(d) );
}
```

Output:

```
a - address: 0x7ffc08c5866c, value: a
b - address: 0x7ffc08c58660, value: 8c5866c
c - address: 0x7ffc08c58658, value: 8c58660
d - address: 0x7ffc08c58650, value: 8c58658
```

which has the difference between the address of `a` and `b` as `0xc`.

then I add:

```
int f = 10;
```

I get this output:

```
f - address: 0x7fff1945656c, value: a
a - address: 0x7fff19456568, value: a
b - address: 0x7fff19456560, value: 19456568
c - address: 0x7fff19456558, value: 19456560
d - address: 0x7fff19456550, value: 19456558
```

The difference between the address of `a` and `b` changed. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Compilers are free to organize memory for your variable as they like... If you want more explanation, read about alignment and padding in C. Also don't forget to print pointer values with `%p`.

Comment: Do you get different addresses running the same program twice?  This could be due to stack placement randomization.

Comment: no, as I add int declarations before int a, the difference between the address of a and the address of b does change from 12 to 4 to 12..

Answer (score 0):

An `int` takes 4 bytes and a pointer takes 8 bytes. The pointer also works "best" if its address is a multiple of 8, that is the hex address ends in 8 or 0.

An `int` likewise has an alignment of 4. So two `int`s could be stored in the same space as one pointer. When you add `f` it uses the first 4 bytes and "pushes" `a` 4 bytes further on. Those bytes were previously unused, so that `b` could start at an 8-byte boundary.

That still leaves room for the pointer `b` to start at the same 0-address it used before.